# Including libraries generating jar and executing with java -jar on Intellij

Tags: java, opencv, compilation

I've been trying to execute a jar file through command line but I'm still getting an exception that I'm missing a library even though it was properly added as it's shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project). The library that I'm trying to run my code with is the opencv's lib. I'm able to run my app from intellij and generate a jar artifact that I can see the jar grows in size when I add the opencv lib but when I try to run the app from the command line with "java -jar Test.jar" I get the message that I'm missing the opencv library.

```
rinaldi@rinaldi-work:~/Projects/Test/out/artifacts/Test_jar$ java -jar Test.jar Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java310 in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
at HelloWorld.<clinit>(HelloWorld.java:14)
at Main.main(Main.java:4)
```

I've also tried to run the app adding the path to the opencv's library:

```
:~/Projects/Test/out/production/Test$ java -cp .:~/Sources/opencv-master/build/bin/opencv-310.jar Main
```

And another attempt because opencv needs not only it's jar but also the /opencv-master/build/lib/ directory:

```
:~/Projects/Test/src$ java -cp :/home/rinaldi/Sources/opencv-master/build/bin/opencv-310.jar:/home/rinaldi/Sources/opencv-master/build/lib/ Main
```

Below are the images from intellij's configuration.

[image: Artifacts window]

[image: Modules window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the library this way:

```
java -jar -Djava.library.path=/home/rinaldi/Sources/opencv-master/build/lib test.jar
```

Hope this helps someone.